# connecting from console app to redis via docker containers

Tags: docker, redis, .net-core

I am trying to connect redis from .net core 2.0 app. both are in docker containers.

I checked if can connect to internet from console app like this and it seems fine;

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string  message = DownloadFile("http://foo.com");

    WriteLine(message);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static string DownloadFile(string remoteFilename)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    return client.DownloadString(remoteFilename);
}
```

I can connect to redis container via Redis Desktop Manager with localhost:6379 and password.

but I can't connect like this;

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    db.StringIncrement("visit");
    Console.WriteLine("Hello. This is your " + db.StringGet("visit") + "th visit");

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static String redisConString = "localhost:6379,password=s7MAdAOqvvINvJZY";

//singleton redis connection instance
public static ConnectionMultiplexer _redisConnection;
public static ConnectionMultiplexer redisConnection
{
    get
    {
        if (_redisConnection == null)
        {
            _redisConnection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisConString);
        }
        return _redisConnection;
    }
}

public static IDatabase _db;
public static IDatabase db
{
    get
    {
        if (_db == null)
        {
            _db = redisConnection.GetDatabase();
        }
        return _db;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For containers running on the same host to be able to communicate, they need to be grouped under a docker network. What you need to do is create a docker network, and attach these container to the network.

```
docker network create --driver bridge my-network
docker run --network=my-network image1 ...
docker run --network=my-network image2 ...
```

For more information check [networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#the-default-bridge-network)

Comment: either that, or use a compose file

Comment: I am getting "Error response from daemon: plugin not found", on dotnet docker which consoleapp runs.